# Gulp not found file gulpfile.js, not running preprocessor

Tags: css, sass, gulp, preprocessor, gulp-watch

I have some problem with gulp... I've clone repo from github, then run npm install. In this repo I have package.json and gulpfile.js I need this gulp for compile scss to css. Gulp should start working after npm install but it won't. When I write 'gulp watchTask' I get:
`Local modules not found in ~\Desktop\app\app-task Try running: npm install.` 
I tried all the hints I found here but it didn't solve my problem...
Could somebody help? Thanks

This is my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
"autoprefixer": "^9.6.0",
"cssnano": "^4.1.10",
"gulp": "^4.0.2",
"gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
"gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
"gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
"gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2"
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: need to see your gulp file too

Comment: also are you running `npm install` and `gulp watchTask` from the correct directory